# I need to show blank as first value

Tags: asp-classic

On my db, I have values from 0 to 24 and this code below populates a dropdown with those values:

```
 <%
    SQLstmt = "Select PriorTries from myTable"
    set TrySet = conn.Execute(SQLstmt)
        %>
        <select name="Tries">
        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        <%
         Do Until TrySet.EOF
          TryID = TrySet("Tries")
         If TryID = Tries Then sel = "SELECTED" Else sel = ""
        %>
        <OPTION Value="<%=TryID%>" <%=sel%> > <%=TrySet("Tries")%>
       <%
        TrySet.MoveNext
        Loop
        %>

      </select>
```

Only problem is the 0 shows up as the default value.

I want blank, just like I have it on the code to be the default value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
             <SELECT name="Tries">
             <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>

               <OPTION Value="0" SELECTED > 0
               <OPTION Value="1"  > 1
               <OPTION Value="2"  > 2
               <OPTION Value="3"  > 3
               <OPTION Value="4"  > 4
               <OPTION Value="5"  > 5
               <OPTION Value="6"  > 6
               <OPTION Value="7"  > 7
               <OPTION Value="8"  > 8
               <OPTION Value="9"  > 9
               <OPTION Value="10"  > 10
               <OPTION Value="11"  > 11
               <OPTION Value="12"  > 12
               <OPTION Value="13"  > 13
               <OPTION Value="14"  > 14
               <OPTION Value="15"  > 15
               <OPTION Value="16"  > 16
               <OPTION Value="17"  > 17
               <OPTION Value="18"  > 18
               <OPTION Value="19"  > 19
               <OPTION Value="20"  > 20
               <OPTION Value="21"  > 21
               <OPTION Value="22"  > 22
               <OPTION Value="23"  > 23
               <OPTION Value="24"  > 24
             </SELECT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see any definition for `Tries`?
Undefined variables are equal to zero (Empty).
So, your if condition in your code returns True while `TrySet("Tries")` is equal to zero (for first record) and prints `SELECTED`. That's normal.
And I interested, you selected column as `PriorTries` in the query but you try getting it with TrySet("`Tries`") in the loop. Do you think that this is correct?
Whatever,
I think you need to try use like that:
`If CStr(TryID) = CStr(Tries) Then sel = "SELECTED" Else sel = ""`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the code above to paste what you requested. As you can see, 0 got SELECTED as default.

Comment: You have two selected's.  You need to add Matt's statement and kill the part of your ASP that generates the SELECTED.  I don't know how your code above runs without an END IF.

Comment: Does TrySet("Tries") equal 0?  By default TrySet("Tries") needs to equal Nothing/Null/or something other than 0 through 24 so you can detect when nothing has been detected versus when 0 was selected.

Comment: Also you are not properly closing your <option> tags.  This won't fix your problem but it is a good idea to close them: <OPTION Value="<%=TryID%>" <%=sel%> > <%=TrySet("Tries")%> </option>

Comment: That ASP part is used to show selected record. This is important for updating records. You want to shwo what the user selected and update it if needed. If no record is selected for the first time, blank is the default. Why is 0 replacing blank as the default value? There is got to be a way of ensuring that selected record becomes the default record and if no record is selected, blank is default, regardless of whether 0 is one of the options or not.

Comment: Kenny, your If TryID = Tries Then sel = "SELECTED" Else sel = "" statement is setting the option with value="0" to selected.  As MikeY said you need to change your code to stop doing that when 0 is not really selected.  (ie. the default).

Comment: Matt,  understand what MikeY is trying to say but if I remove that If TriyID... sel="SELECTED"... it will mess up the code. Selected value will no longer render correctly. Infact, it will either not show any value or it defaults to last value, in this case, 24. That's not the solution I am looking for. If anyone has any syntax that I can use in place of the IF..., I would be grateful for it. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Kenny, when nothing is selected your database is returning 0 so that is getting selected by your if statement.  Without knowing more it is very hard to help.  Can you show what your SqlStmt="Select PriorTries from myTable" returns when the user has no record selected?

Comment: Mat, you are right! It returns a 0 on the db when no records are selected from the statement you posted. WOW! Before I added that 0 into the dropdown as an option, when you view source, it would show <option ="">&nbsp;</option> So, how come that is entering a 0?

Comment: OK, I am sorry for wasting you guys' time. I figured out the problem. The asp version of the code that I pasted here actually works as posted. The problem is that on the processing page, I have this: Tries = CLng("0" & Request.Form("Tries")). So, it doesn't matter what you do, it sticks a 0 there. I did this app like 3 yrs ago and just remembered to look there. Thanks for all your time and contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Default your selected variable to -1. Because 0 is the default value, it's selected. I don't think you need selected='selected'. It's just selected like you have it with your valued options. My guess is your recordset has a count in it, which is returning zero. Maybe in your SQL script, if the value is zero, return -1 or null.